# I am trying to build a npm package after forking it from github but i am getting this error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

This is the github repo - https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist

when i run the package command

```
rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig-esm.json && rollup -c rollup.config.js dist/ngx-gist.module.js > dist/ngx-gist.bundle.js && cp package.json dist && ts-node tools/cleanup.ts && ngc && cp README.md dist
```

I get the following error -

```
/usr/lib/nodejs/typescript/tsc.js:37290
            var jsonOptions = json["compilerOptions"];
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilerOptions' of undefined
```

How to fix this error ?

**UPDATE**

compiler options

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "files": [
    "./lib/ngx-gist.module.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file tsconfig-esm.json is located in the root dir of your project, most likely there is an issue with the formatting of this JSON file. It has to be structured as follows:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    ...
   }
}
```

The other possible reason is that you use an old version of tsc on your computer.

Comment: if you check that repo i am cloning and just running the command and still the error , it already has npm package . i will update the compiler options 2